# Iterating javascript array with 2 elements

Tags: javascript

I am having `array<array<>>` (nested arrays) in javasccirpt. Inner array is an array with just two elements.I am doing followint for iteraring my given array.

```
 const finaldata = InitialData.map(Data => {
  first_element = Data[0];
  //Do some logic using first_element

  second_element =Data[1];
  //Do some logic using second_element different from what done for first element.

  return something;

  })
```

What I am afraid is iterating inner array using indexes 0 and 1 (I think its risky in doing that) . Can someone give me better way of doing this ?

Comment: Can you explain why you think it's risky to do that?

Comment: I have heard its risky to index array without checking null conditions. Maybe for Data[1], index 1 doesnot exist. Data here is a result of sql query from php.

Comment: You said that the inner arrays have two elements. Does not every array have two elements?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using indexes really. If you want to be safe you should include some verification code to make sure the inner array has two elements, no less. Otherwise you might want to consider using some dedicated object instead of array if it has such a well defined structure of 2 elements.

Comment: Data is comming from sql query, Can assume its always 2 elements ?

Comment: If this is Javascript, indexing an element that does not exist in the array will return `undefined`. You can check for undefined and handle it however you want.

Comment: just check if `Data.length >= 2`

Comment: Can't you just do a nested map ?

Comment: @ DavidDomain , I have different things to do for both first and second element

Comment: @crystal you can still use a nested map. The second argument to the callback function will give you the index of the current element being processed.

Comment: Can you explain with an example ? Would be really helpful :)

Comment: @crystal Can you post a sample of your data and be a bit more specific with what you are actually trying to do?

Comment: @DavidDomain I'd say a nested map is not really worth it when the number of array elements does not exceed 2.

Comment: @Tomalak If that is actually the case, i'd say you're right. The OP just mentioned, that he or she is assuming that it is always 2, but anyway, if i think about it, in any case it is probably not necessary. ; )

Answer (score 2):

if you want to be sure just check

```
 const finaldata = InitialData.map(Data => {
  first_element = Data[0];
  //Do some logic using first_element

  second_element =Data[1];
  //Do some logic using second_element different from what done for first element.

  //simple checking
  if (first_element) {
    ...
  }
  if (second_element) {
    ...
  }

  return something;

})
```

Comment: ` second_element =Data[1]; ` here you are accesing index 1 , even if its not present . Wouldn't that lead to out of bounds kind of error ?

Comment: var a = [];
console.log(a[100]) // undefined
there will be no error, just undefined

Answer (score 0):

If you want to strict for exactly two inner elements
maybe you should use Map<,> instead of Array, this will enforce a [key,value] pairs.

here I created a polyfill for the Map.prototype.map function:

```
Map.prototype.map = function(mapf) { var aMap = this; var thisArg = arguments[1] || aMap; return [...aMap].map(([key,value]) => mapf.call(aMap, value, key, thisArg)); };
```

then you us it like your code before, try the snippet:

```js
let InitialData = new Map()
.set(1, 'a')
.set(2, 'b')
.set(3, 'c');

//- polyfill  -//
Map.prototype.map = function(mapf) { 
  var aMap = this; 
  var thisArg = arguments[1] || aMap; 
  return [...aMap].map(([key,value]) => mapf.call(aMap, value, key, thisArg)); 
};
//- /polyfill  -//

const finaldata = InitialData.map((second_element, first_element)  => {
  console.log(first_element);//Do some logic using first_element

  console.log(second_element + '-addition');//Do some logic using second_element different from what done for first element.
    
  return first_element+second_element;
});

console.log(finaldata);
```